# Find and replace relative url with url from database - PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, database

I'm trying to to find internal links in html e.g.

```
<p>This is first <a href="/old-link-first">old link</a> and this is second <a href="/old-link-second">old link</a></p>
```

I have to match relative links make query on database in order to get links from database, I have problem with matching :/ and executing.

I tried with this but it seems to work only with first link:

```
$out='<p>This is first <a href="/old-link-first">old link</a> and this is second <a href="/old-link-second">old link</a></p>';

$pattern = '/href="\/(.*)?"/';

function ch($match){
    $oldurl = 'href="'.$match[1].'"';
    // query to database
    return $newurl;
}

$out = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'ch', $out);
print $out;
```

Probably I have lots of mistakes 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't worked that much with `preg_replace_callback` but I guess It only does one match so what you might do instead, is calling a function and use preg_replace_callback within that function so it loops until everything is replaced, as can be seen by the third example in the [php documentations](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

**Something like this maybe:**

```
<?PHP
$out='<p>This is first <a href="/old-link-first">old link</a> and this is second <a href="/old-link-second">old link</a></p>';

function ch($match){
    $pattern = '/href="\/(.*)?"/';
    if(is_array($match)){
    $match = 'href="'.$match[1].'"';
    }
    // query to database

    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'ch', $match);
}

$out = ch($out);
print $out;
```